# Proving f: $\epsilon --> \epsilon$ defined by $f(x,y) = (x + y^2, y^3)$ is a transformation

Tags: geometry

So far, I understand that we need to show the function $f(x,y) = (x + y^2, y^3)$ is bijective and therefore, a transformation. So, let us map from (x,y) to (u,v).

$ u = x + y^2$ and $v = y^3$. From here, we know that y will be unique because it is a cube root and then obtain $x = v^{2/3} - u$.

How do I show that $x = v^{2/3} - u$ will map one-to-one and hence, make f(x,y) bijective?

Comment: What is $\epsilon$. To show $f$ is a bijection, all one has to do is to find a map $g$ in the opposite direction such that $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ are identities.

Comment: I think it simply is a mapping from the plane to another plane. It's \varepsilon -> \varepsilon if that clears anything up. Does that mean I simply need an inverse function?

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x,y)=f(a,b)$ then

$x+y^3=a+b^3$ and $y^3=b^3$. Hence $x=a$ and $y^3=b^3$. This gives $(x,y)=(a,b)$.

Conclusion: $f$ is injective.